# What needs to be installed for `iconv` to work with PHP8

Tags: php, github-actions, php-8

I'm trying to migrate `doctrine/rst-parser` to Github actions, and the last hurdle is a test that fails because of a call to `iconv`:

`iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text)`

The test fails with

```
Failed asserting that two strings are identical.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
     <li class="dash">Test list item 1.</li>
     <li class="dash">Test list item 2.</li>
 </ul>
-<p class="rot-gelb-blau grun-2008">Weird class names.</p>
+<p class="rot-gelb-blau grn-2008">Weird class names.</p>
```

I have tried installing the `libc6` ubuntu package, and installing the `iconv` and `intl` PHP extensions, no dice. What should I try?

Here is a link to the pull request: https://github.com/doctrine/rst-parser/pull/126

EDIT: [the solution seems to be to do a `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US');`](https://3v4l.org/5qUNT), but that returns `false` on github actions for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf8')` fixes the issue. This is required since PHP 8: https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/c4ad8beaa890b931031a5cf8a1d2d38550fca3af